# SQLite database in memory

Tags: java, sqlite, memory

I need to find a way to run an SQLite database in memory, or some form of database that can host itself in memory. It is very performance orientated and I cannot afford the IO that a standard file-based system would use.

I originally went with SQLite is due to how keeps itself to one file and doesn't require an additional service to run, unfortunately I can't find a way to run it in memory though.

I've looked at options such as HSQLDB, although it doesn't seem to be what I am after.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: Isn't it easier to Google "sqlite run in memory" and select the TOP HIT than write a question on SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run SQLite [in memory](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), just use the database name `:memory:`.

Comment: Extremely late reply, but thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to load an existing sqlite database file in memory? This instruction is to create a new in memory database

Comment: @nellowl That would be a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718057/does-sqlite3-support-loading-from-string-bytes-instead-of-file).

Answer (score 2):

[H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) is an open source and pure Java database engine that supports in-memory databases.

Ditto for [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)

Both can be run inside your app via *embedded* mode, instead of being run in server mode.

Comment: Uh, anyway to not have the server running? Reading the documentation, it appears to require it to operate :/ I need it to run completely inside of the Java application

Comment: "Embedded" means running inside your app as opposed to running as a database server. H2 runs either way. Look at first paragraph of first page of [first link](http://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html) under Documentation nav panel.