# Does sqlite3 support loading from string/bytes instead of file?

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, sqlite

`sqlite3` supports dumping to and opening from `.db` file and file is actually a container of string/bytes, so I have the question.

I store `.db` file on cdn server and have a client (maybe `python`, `javascript` or `ruby`) to send HTTP request. After having received HTTP response, I intend to open a temporary db from response body instead of saving it to file and opening from file. In this case, all is done in memory without access to local file system. Is this possible or I am going the wrong way?

Comment: [In-Memory Databases](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)

Comment: @MikeT The 1st and the 3rd create an empty db. How can I load data? And the 2nd seems to support only `file` scheme not `http`.

Comment: You create tables and insert data using sql in the empty database, same as you would in a not in-memory database.

Comment: @MikeT That is not as expected. The `.db` file on the server already has data. I expect I can do query right after I open the db.

Comment: If you want to access data in the file, you have to open it, not an in-memory database.

Answer (score 3):

This would be possible with the function [sqlite3_deserialize()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/deserialize.html), if you were using C.